# PHP multidimensional array generating tabs in html and controlling the content

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, tabs

I am trying to generate tabs through a PHP multidimensional array and browse through the content through these tabs. So, I want to have 4 tabs with 4 contents. Help me, please. Here is my code.

```
 <? $tabs = array(
    array(
    'title' => 'Title 1',
    'content' => 'Content1'
    ),
    array(
    'title' => 'Title 2',
    'content' => 'Content 2'
    ),
    array(
    'title' => 'Title 3',
    'content' => 'Content 3'
    ),
    array(
    'title' => 'Title 4',
    'content' => 'Content 4'
    )
    ); 
    ?>
```

So, I want the value of title to be the header of each tab, "Title, 1, 2, 3" etc... and the value of content to be the content of each tab. I hope you got what I am trying to do.
Here is the rest of my code of what I've managed to do so far. I am able to echo out the tabs and the content like I want, but how can I control the content through the tabs? Please help.

```
 <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
 <? foreach($tabs as $tab){
 <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-" aria-selected="true"><? echo $tab['title'];?></a></li>
 <? } ?>
 </ul>
 <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
 <? foreach($tabs as $tab) { ?>
 <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel">
 <p><? echo $tab['content'];?> </p>
 </div>
 <? } ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean `control content`?

Comment: Link to bootstrap tab usage is here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage

Comment: To switch through the content with the click of each tab, and each content to change for the tab clicked.

Comment: See the link, there's no need to rewrite it here.

Comment: I use Foundation 6 though, not bootstrap, how can I do it with Foundation 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code almost correct except id of tab what you can correct is as follows

```
 <ul class="tabs" id="example-tabs" data-tabs>
 <?php foreach($tabs as $index => $tab):?>
    <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-<?php echo $index;?>" aria-selected="true"><?php echo $tab['title'];?></a></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>

 <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
 <?php foreach($tabs as $index => $tab):?>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-<?php echo $index;?>">
        <p><?php echo $tab['content'];?> </p>
    </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
```

**Here is test results**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php
 $tabs = array(
    array(
    'title' => 'Title 1',
    'content' => 'Content1'
    ),
    array(
    'title' => 'Title 2',
    'content' => 'Content 2'
    ),
    array(
    'title' => 'Title 3',
    'content' => 'Content 3'
    ),
    array(
    'title' => 'Title 4',
    'content' => 'Content 4'
    )
    ); 
?>

 <ul class="tabs" id="example-tabs" data-tabs>
 <?php foreach($tabs as $index => $tab):?>
    <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-<?php echo $index;?>" aria-selected="true"><?php echo $tab['title'];?></a></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>

 <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
 <?php foreach($tabs as $index => $tab):?>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-<?php echo $index;?>">
        <p><?php echo $tab['content'];?> </p>
    </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
```

**Would produce HTML as follows**

[JSFiddle Sample Results](https://jsfiddle.net/L57kL5xf/)

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php

 <ul class="tabs" id="example-tabs" data-tabs>
    <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-0" aria-selected="true">Title 1</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-1" aria-selected="true">Title 2</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-2" aria-selected="true">Title 3</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-3" aria-selected="true">Title 4</a></li>
  </ul>

 <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-0">
        <p>Content1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-1">
        <p>Content 2 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-2">
        <p>Content 3 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-3">
        <p>Content 4 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey hi! Thanks! But even with your code and Foundation 6 on, I can't get the Content 1, 2, 3, 4 below any tab and change it through the click of a tab... please help me do it

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @VladimirB. you may consider accept if you think it solved your issue